# How to use cookies to login to website?

Tags: security, cookies, curl, session-cookies, wget

I have logged into a website and saved the respective cookies in a text file. Now I want to login to the same website using :-

1. Command Line utility like wget/curl without user name and password using those cookies.
2. Login into the website via browser using cookies without entering username and password.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, just login and look at the Network tab of Inspector. If you right click on a request, there's an option that says *Copy as cURL*.

Comment: `man curl`/`man wget`

Comment: Use `Edit This Cookie` on Chrome to paste in the values.

Comment: For `curl, have a look at `--cookie <name=data>` OR `--cookie-jar <file name>`